# database design store transactions

Tags: database-design

For a project I am required to create a system which allows sales of items, basically an EPOS system. I have it mostly working but I cannot think of a good way in which to store transactions.

As a transactions would have one or more items, and I need to know what the items are how would I store this in the transactions table? Can I have CSV within a field in the table to store more than one product ID?

```
transactionID
noItems
itemID <- Store more than one?
cost
```

Any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Transactions
-------
TransactionId
TotalCost

TransactionItems
-----------
transactionId
ItemId

Items
-----------
ItemId
ItemName
Price
```

Do NOT store multiple values in a single field.  This will make your database world a living hell.